# OpenCl 2.0 easy example

Tags: c++, opencl

I have compiled an OpenCL 2.0. example that is found here: https://tobias.rautenkranz.ch/opencl2/
I get the following runtime error: No source available for "cl::Platform::setDefault() at 0x4187a4".
This happens after I press resume once in the Eclipse run menu.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and eclipse.
From what I understood from googleing the problem it's a threads problem, but I'm new to the area so it's not easy for me to understand!

Comment: That means that there was a problem in `cl::Platform::setDefault()` (which is in the OpenCL C++ wrapper API) but you don't have access to its source code. It's not an error in itself, and is normal with pre-built libraries. Wasn't there an earlier error message when you dropped into the debugger?

Comment: There was one: No source available for "main() at 0x41739f"